# Return user input into setter function

Tags: java

I have been working on an assignment and i am stuck at here. Basically i have 1 class which defines all functions and members.

And another class to initialize and manipulate objects.

Here is my first class code.

```
public class cyryxStudent_association {

String studentID, studentName, studentCourse_level, studentTitle;
int course_completed_year;
static double registration_fee;
double activity_fee;
double total_amt;

//Default constructor
cyryxStudent_association ()
{
    studentID = "Null";
    studentName = "Null";
    studentCourse_level = "Null";
    studentTitle = "Null";
    course_completed_year = 0;
}

//Parameterized Constructor
cyryxStudent_association (String id, String name, String course_level, String title, int ccy)
{
    this.studentID = id;
    this.studentName = name;
    this.studentCourse_level = course_level;
    this.studentTitle = title;
    this.course_completed_year = ccy;
}

//Getters
public String getStudentID ()
{
    return studentID;
}
public String getStudentName ()
{
    return studentName;
}
public String getStudentCourse_level ()
{
    return studentCourse_level;
}
public String getStudentTitle ()
{
    return studentTitle;
}
public int getCourse_completed_year ()
{
    return course_completed_year;
}
public double getRegistration_fee ()
{
    return registration_fee;
}
public double getActivity_fee ()
{
    return findActivity_fee(registration_fee);
}
public double getTotal_amt ()
{
    return total_amt(registration_fee, activity_fee);
}

//Setters
public void setStudentID (String id)
{
    studentID = id;
}
public void setStudentName (String name)
{
    studentName = name;
}
public void setStudentCourse_level (String course_level)
{
    studentCourse_level = course_level;
}
public void setStudentTitle (String title)
{
    studentTitle = title;
}
public void setCourse_completed_year (int ccy)
{
    course_completed_year = ccy;
}

//Find registration fee method
public static double findRegistration_fee (String course_level)
{
    if (course_level.equalsIgnoreCase("Certificate"))
    {
        registration_fee = 75;
    }
    else if (course_level.equalsIgnoreCase("Diploma"))
    {
        registration_fee = 100;
    }
    else if (course_level.equalsIgnoreCase("Degree"))
    {
        registration_fee = 150;
    }
    else if (course_level.equalsIgnoreCase("Master"))
    {
        registration_fee = 200;
    }

    return registration_fee;
}

//Find activity method
public static double findActivity_fee (double registration_fee)
{
    return registration_fee * 0.25;
}

//Find total amount
public static double total_amt (double registration_fee, double activity_fee)
{
    return registration_fee + activity_fee;
}

//To string method
public String toString ()
{
    return "ID: "+getStudentID()+"\nName: "+getStudentName()+"\nCourse Level: 
   "+getStudentCourse_level()+"\nTitle: "+getStudentTitle()+"\nCourse Completed Year: 
   "+getCourse_completed_year()+"\nRegistration Fee: "+getRegistration_fee()+"\nActivity Fee: 
   "+getActivity_fee()+"\nTotal Amount: "+getTotal_amt ();
}
}
```

And here is my second class code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test_cyryxStudent_association {

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    int num, i;

    System.out.println("Welcome!");
    System.out.println("\nEnter the number of students: ");
    num = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();

    cyryxStudent_association Std[] = new cyryxStudent_association[num];

    for (i = 0; i < Std.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("\nEnter ID: ");
        Std[i].setStudentID(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter Name: ");
        Std[i].setStudentName(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter Course Level [Certificate, Diploma, Degree, Master]: ");
        Std[i].setStudentCourse_level(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter Title: ");
        Std[i].setStudentTitle(sc.nextLine());

        Std[i].getRegistration_fee();
        Std[i].getActivity_fee();
        Std[i].getTotal_amt();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < Std.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("\nStudent " + i + 1 + " Information");
        System.out.println("===================================");
        Std[i].toString();
    }


    sc.close();
}
}
```

I get an error when values in the for loop. Can someone help me? I'm pretty new to programming and studying java for 2 months now. What am i doing wrong?

Here is my objectives.

1. Create an array of objects and get user input for number of objects to be manipulated.
2. Read and display array of object values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the objects of your array.
After the line:

```
cyryxStudent_association Std[] = new cyryxStudent_association[num];
```

do a for loop like:

```
for(i = 0; i<std.length; i++){
    std[i] = new cyryxStudent_association();
}
```